# how to add .apklib in eclipse application buildpath

Tags: android, apklib

How to add .apklib as dependency into the build path in eclipse ??
I have an app which is dependent on another library(of type apklib). I want to build my app in eclipse but get compilation error for all the classes referred in dependent apklib library.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that you have is the apklib?
If yes, I advise you to use MAVEN, and put the apklib in a repository path (or certify that is already not exists).
If no, just add the source code of the another projet to yours.